# PHP - Split string into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php string that looks like this...

```
[line1]this is some test text[/line1][line2]This is line 2 text[/line2][line3]This is line 3 text[/line3]
```

I am trying to take this and create an array that looks like this..

```
array(
    "line1"=>"this is some test text",
    "line2"=>"This is line 2 text",
    "line3"=>"This is line 3 text"
)
```

The string is dynamically created so it could consist of line1 - line 99 and so on.

What is the best way to do this and keep it scalable?  Does anybody have an example they can point me at?

Comment: Use `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: Use one capture group to match the `[lineX]` part, and another to match everything until `[/lineX]`. `preg_match_all()` returns a 2-dimensional array, you can loop through that to convert it to an associative array.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: I think I have the basic concept of preg_match_all down, but now trying to work out how to deal with unknown X

Comment: `\d+` will match unknown number of digits.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: I'm really tempted to suggest trying to covert your tokens into html/xml tags so you can run them through DOMDocument or SImpleXML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take this approach (by splitting the input string multiple times) with `explode` in order to isolate the relevant data: **line-id** and the **line-text**:

```
$text = "[line1]this is some test text[/line1][line2]This is line 2 text[/line2][line3]This is line 3 text[/line3]";

$text = explode( '][line', ']'.$text.'[line');

// you'll get a spurious item at index 0 and at the end, they'll be skipped

$n = count( $text );

$output = array();

for( $i = 1; $i < $n - 1; $i++ )
{
    $line = explode( ']', $text[ $i] );
    $id = 'line' . $line[ 0 ];
    $line = explode( '[', $line[ 1 ] );
    $value = $line[ 0 ];
    $output[ $id ] = $value;
}

var_export( $output );
echo "\n";
```

You get:

```
array (
  'line1' => 'this is some test text',
  'line2' => 'This is line 2 text',
  'line3' => 'This is line 3 text',
)
```

**Note:**

Empty "lines" are tolerated and preperly handled

A square brake inside the `line` text would break the code and screw everything up.

The input format must be scrictly in the form

`[line`***n***`]`***text***`[/line`***n***`]`....

If you have further requirements you may adjust the code.

I think this may be a good starting point.

**Note (again):**

This is a working solution (given the restictions mentinoned above).

Another approach is to go with regular expressions and `preg_match_all()` using capturing groups to retrieve line id and line text.

Comment: Thanks, this is working well.  But I am having issues with <p> tags breaking things

Comment: well now you mention that this is parsing html, then regex is completely useless. You should of mentioned this in the question, now the solutions provided are all but useless to you. You need to use a xmlparser instead

Comment: Sorry, ignore that comment.  It's not a <p> tag, it's new lines \r\n that are breaking things

Comment: newlines should not break things with my solution.

Answer (score 2):

As far as regex go, this may be a reasonable compromise for a matching pattern.

note: *This will not deal with nested/recursion.*

`\[([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[/\g{1}\]`

Usage:

```
preg_match_all( '%\[([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[/\g{1}\]%', $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
var_dump( $matches );
```

---

```
Match the character “[” literally «\[»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\]]+)»
   Match any character that is NOT a “]” «[^\]]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “]” literally «\]»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (lazy) «*»
Match the character “[” literally «\[»
Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match the same text that was most recently matched by capturing group number 1 (case sensitive; fail if the group did not participate in the match so far) «\g{1}»
Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```